# Urlencode in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, urlencode

i'm trying to make url encode for long string by using this function

```
    NSData   *PostData   = [MyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxx.com/save.php"]];

   [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setHTTPBody:PostData];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

but i miss some data when save it to my sql
for example if we have this string which contain special characters

> ("Text !@# & *(* | 'l;,. ") and < smile faces

when this string receive to my server i miss string after this & and after smile faces ?!

Comment: Anything wrong with using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, that won't percent escape certain characters (notably `+` and `&` are problematic). You should use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't show us how you created the `MyData` variable or what type it is, but I'm guessing it's a `NSString` that you might have constructed something like the following:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", parameterKey, parameterValue];
NSData   *postData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What you need to do is to "percent escape" any characters that are defined as reserved per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Thus, you'd replace the above with:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", parameterKey, [self percentEScapeString:parameterValue]];
NSData   *postData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

where

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Technically, per [the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should replace spaces with `+` characters, thus:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

Personally, I put these sorts of methods in a `NSString` category, rather than in the current class, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Regardless, do *not* be tempted to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, because that doesn't give you the control you need. You really need to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, as shown above.

---

You asked about the emoticons. The above percent escaping works fine with the emoticons. For example, consider:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Text !@# & ( | 'l;,. ";
NSString *string2 = [self percentEscapeString:string1];
NSString *string3 = [string2 stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", string1);
NSLog(@"%@", string2);
NSLog(@"%@", string3);
```

```
2013-12-25 18:20:16.391 PercentEncodeTest[67199:70b] Text !@# & ( | 'l;,. 
2013-12-25 18:20:16.397 PercentEncodeTest[67199:70b] Text%20%21%40%23%20%26%20%28%20%7C%20%27l%3B%2C.%20%F0%9F%98%92%F0%9F%98%9A%F0%9F%98%9C
2013-12-25 18:20:16.401 PercentEncodeTest[67199:70b] Text !@# & ( | 'l;,.
```

As you can see, `string2` is entirely percent escaped and should be correctly transmitted. And when we convert back to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, we get our emoticons back fine.

I suspect that the problem now is not in the fact that the emoticons are correctly percent escaped, but rather your use of them by the destination.

Comment: Work well but same problem if there smile faces in my string how to fix that

Comment: Might depend on the server. Technically domains can now be almost any Unicode character. (Russia is a place where URLs are popular in Cyrillic for example. ) but not all software handles this well yet.

Comment: @Fawaz The smiley characters are properly encoded (as illustrated in my revised answer). The question is what you mean by "same problem if there are smile faces". Using this percent escape encoding, you should be able to send these strings and not have them prematurely terminated or anything untoward. The question is what your server is doing with this string.

Answer (score 0):

## As of iOS9,

```
[url_string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```