# NSURL Not Accepting Backslash Character

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm developing an iOS app and trying to create an NSURL for a PHP page, and I need to escape the apostrophe's for PHP with: \'   Below is an example of a URL I tried to escape the apostrophe :

```
http:/www.name.com/receive.php?name=hello\'s
```

The problem is that the backslash character isn't allowed in NSURLs. And before anyone says, I already tried "\ \'" so that isn't the issue. The issue is with the backslash itself, I guess they just simply aren't allowed in NSURLs. How can I get around this?

Comment: hi... can you please tell what is your expected URL from above url.

Comment: Try `http:/www.name.com/receive.php?name=hello\\'s`

Comment: @AshokLondhe The URL will follow this format: http://www.private.com/recievedata.php?item=someitem&contact=somecontact&discovery=discovery&summary=description now some of the values for item, contact, discovery, and summary may have apostrophes. That's where the problem is. In order to keep those apostrophes I need to escape them with a backslash, but the backslash isn't allowed in NSURLs.

Comment: @RicetongTan The issue is the backslash itself, NSURL does not allow it.

Comment: @Dragon That is a PHP function, I'm creating the NSURL in objective-C.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If needed, update your previous question with additional details.

Comment: @pwoerfulafhjksdh if my answer helps you mark it as a accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
NSString *s=@"http:/www.name.com/receive.php?name=hello\'s";
s=[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\"]];

NSLog(@"s=%@",s);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:s];

NSLog(@"url=%@",url);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I already said so in my description. The problem is with the backslash itself. NSURL does not permit it.

Comment: That's not going to help. All you did is replace the backslash and apostrophe with nothing. I need to keep the backslash, not get rid of it.

Comment: @pwoerfulafhjksdh You can use encoding for the url string like this way 
`NSString *str = @"";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Comment: @VijayMasiwal - Yes, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is better than this backslash silliness, which is entirely misguided. But it won't percent escape the `'` character. He really should use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` (using alphanumeric plus `-`, `.`, `_`, and `~`) or use [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777112/urlencode-in-objective-c/20777164#20777164). Unfortunately, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` eliminates the `nil` result for `NSURL`, but doesn't solve the deeper problem here.

Comment: @Rob Thanks you for your suggestion. Actually  i have not study so much on this topic. so i use \ and it works so i posted my answer. if you know the better you can feel free to edit my answer and guide me if i am doing any mistake.

Comment: The OP is, unfortunately, conflating two completely different issues, namely the need to escape `'` characters in string values in his PHP code, and the proper way to send `'` character in a value in a request (which is governed by [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)). The whole backslash aspect of his question is, with all due respect, a complete misunderstanding on his part.

Comment: @Rob can you please correct my answer. and also explain me how it work.

Comment: @AshokLondhe Since this question was closed, I posted an answer under his duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30389018/1271826.